# I want to receive Google Chat messages from my work account but I don't want work emails showing up in my Gmail app

Tags: gmail, google-chat

I use the Gmail app on my phone for my personal accounts. My work uses Google Chat and Gmail for all communications. The problem is, adding my work account for Chat causes it to also bring in my work emails, which I don't want on my phone.

Is there any way of getting Gmail to ignore an account? Or maybe a way to get the Chat notifications without adding the account to my device?

Comment: There's no way other then use a phone (e.g. some Xiaomi) that allows managing and switching between different users/profiles. With different users you can have personal and work separated as you want.